# Collapse Event - Show, how to get selected element

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can I add a class to the `.accordion-group`, so that it would only ever have one selected class showing the open accordion?

I see form the docs I could do:

```
$('#myCollapsible').on('show', function () {
// do something…
})
```

But how do I get the new element? `$(this)` return the `$('#myCollapsible')` which is a `ul`

jSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KVdfT/1/

Docs: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse

Comment: The main group container of the selected element should have a active class

Comment: May I point you to my own confusion? And the quote from [the only current answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14877657/82548): "if I understand your question correctly" So no, what you want is not obvious. But you're clearly entitled to not clarify your question, if you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly:

```
$("#myCollapsible").on("shown", function () {
    $(".foo", this).removeClass("foo");
    $(".in", this).parent().addClass("foo");
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/KVdfT/6/

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I have been trying but $(this) refers to `#myCollapsible` and not the currently selected child.

Comment: Ah yes now that we are using the shown, we can search for the .in. Brilliant thanks